# Why does this .indexOn: 'g' no longer work as it should?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I can no longer place activeDrivers in the correct position to make it work. "acriveDrivers" is a direct branch of the root, so the way I placed it is as if it were a child of drivers, which seems wrong to me, but I can't find the solution.

**The rules at the beginning were like this (practically no security):**

```
{
      "rules": {
        ".read":true,
        ".write": true,
          "activeDrivers": {
          ".indexOn": ["g"]
        }
      }
}
```

**New rules are:**

```
 "rules": {
         "drivers": {
            "$uid": {
              ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
              ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
                   "activeDrivers": {
                        ".indexOn": ["g"]
                    } 
            }
           
         }
}
```

**This is the JSON of the Database:**

```
{
  "ALL Ride Requests": {
    "-NJlIOrp49pNBSuuEawT": {
      "destination": {
        "latitude": "41.929612",
        "longitude": "12.4858561"
      },
      "destinationAddress": "Duke's",
      "driverId": "waiting",
      "origin": {
        "latitude": "41.919225",
        "longitude": "12.5266267"
      },
      "originAddress": "Circonvallazione Nomentana, 270, 00162 Roma RM, Italy",
      "time": "2022-12-20 21:50:48.437521",
      "userName": "Peter Parker",
      "userPhone": "090012321354"
    },
  },
  "activeDrivers": {
    "31uMBJKvl6PF7BVKQnqHORTrWRP2": {
      ".priority": "sr2yt23wk8",
      "g": "sr2yt23wl8",
      "l": [
        41.926275,
        12.5376567
      ]
    },
    "G3OJ79KiLeMmxqoUpJ1NggIKbiF2": {
      ".priority": "sr2yt23wk8",
      "g": "sr2yt23rk8",
      "l": [
        41.926275,
        12.5376567
      ]
    },
    "filTJu3xjiQYTzehD71kzY1Oybz1": {
      ".priority": "sr2yt23wk8",
      "g": "sr2yy23wk8",
      "l": [
        41.926275,
        12.5376567
      ]
    }
  },
  "drivers": {
    "G3OJ79KiLeMmxqoUpJ1NggIKbiF2": {
      "earnings": "0.0",
      "email": "simo@hotmail.it",
      "id": "G3OJ79KiLeMmxqoUpJ1NggIKbiF2",
      "name": "Simone Demichele Test",
      "newRideStatus": "idle",
      "password": "testpassword",
      "phone": "3452362585",
      "token": "fFIwv1IHRv2ylXyW-qRVGQ:APA91bH7IfcNBBi7Y53wRjQKN12-nBUgFHHpf7F0LeWCstG_MIqt-mkobRN6nvUZxqbMnMlXU2yMHdE-efYykUdtcXl-91wW5rGyQcpMl6Dij6bxC8snQRkAMGBhQUmyqYW6sBhY6Ul3"
    },
    "Gzs0qxNiE6VZrwNGPYpFPRB7J8p1": {
      "email": "giacomo@gmail.com",
      "id": "Gzs0qxNiE6VZrwNGPYpFPRB7J8p1",
      "name": "giacomo",
      "newRideStatus": "idle",
      "phone": "134634564352",
      "token": "cdG8W0lFRZ2F0jAeG2WbnO:APA91bHTtbtSg18sPNxcH92TIdM3UuX-qcim2-h0I_1YPcBgucIGO0I3ACIQEGVpmsg-EKcRZXFIMIXlxGk1iBw-V0hmDZBVWDyFh44yH2iM8fZgrhRsQzyVBdXdLxGMI0Vz67hQFUQU"
    },
    "OLhsoowb9FXTBtWQmGysGLLBgNz2": {
      "email": "gino@gmail.com",
      "id": "OLhsoowb9FXTBtWQmGysGLLBgNz2",
      "name": "Gino",
      "phone": "4568965432",
      "token": "ewktnxHKRSCBWwilm_SDfd:APA91bFchfCs_33zZNGNtbUHPf6TBC3Vrua7U4QT0bX_e4cr6Z62XSPr5TwZyL-BQ12fmDa3XKnAqeLDQy7NMUKp9m8bq676jS_i5n1vjNMFYJ4tHfIYjntEwYKvOcsTp0yh4ZSvjuxb"
    },
    "ZYqM7SbG3IhRBAGCfXRZHHs7XdG3": {
      "email": "laura@gmail.com",
      "id": "ZYqM7SbG3IhRBAGCfXRZHHs7XdG3",
      "name": "Laura",
      "newRideStatus": "idle",
      "phone": "1212432554325",
      "token": "cdG8W0lFRZ2F0jAeG2WbnO:APA91bHTtbtSg18sPNxcH92TIdM3UuX-qcim2-h0I_1YPcBgucIGO0I3ACIQEGVpmsg-EKcRZXFIMIXlxGk1iBw-V0hmDZBVWDyFh44yH2iM8fZgrhRsQzyVBdXdLxGMI0Vz67hQFUQU"
    },
    "filTJu3xjiQYTzehD71kzY1Oybz1": {
      "email": "maria@gmail.com",
      "id": "filTJu3xjiQYTzehD71kzY1Oybz1",
      "name": "Maria",
      "newRideStatus": "idle",
      "phone": "3726761919",
      "token": "fFIwv1IHRv2ylXyW-qRVGQ:APA91bH7IfcNBBi7Y53wRjQKN12-nBUgFHHpf7F0LeWCstG_MIqt-mkobRN6nvUZxqbMnMlXU2yMHdE-efYykUdtcXl-91wW5rGyQcpMl6Dij6bxC8snQRkAMGBhQUmyqYW6sBhY6Ul3"
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "yHc7xseCT0QePnpolGHZvdr8ARV2": {
      "email": "peter@gmail.com",
      "id": "yHc7xseCT0QePnpolGHZvdr8ARV2",
      "name": "Peter Parker",
      "phone": "090012321354"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the query**

```
Position pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );
    driverCurrentPosition = pos;

    Geofire.initialize("activeDrivers");
    
    Geofire.setLocation(
        currentFirebaseUser!.uid,
        driverCurrentPosition!.latitude,
        driverCurrentPosition!.longitude
    );
```

Comment: Can you also share a sample dataset JSON of your database and the query that you are trying to run ?

Comment: I have now added.